# Add drop shadow without an offset to movieclip

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am trying to add a drop shadow look( without the offset) to a movie clip in Flash. 
Using the Actionscript below, I can add a drop shadow with an offset.

```
import flash.filters.DropShadowFilter;

var dropShadow:DropShadowFilter = new DropShadowFilter(5, 45, 0x333333, 20, 10, 10, 1, 2, false, false, false); 
container_mc.filters = new Array(dropShadow);
```

How can I create a drop shadow effect  without any offset ( all around the movie clip)?

Answer (score 2):

You can start with setting [the distance property](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/filters/DropShadowFilter.html#distance) to zero.

```
var dropShadow:DropShadowFilter = new DropShadowFilter(0, 45, 0x333333, 20, 10, 10, 1, 2, false, false, false);
container_mc.filters = [dropShadow]; // the brackets are shorthand for a new array
```

If that's not to your liking, try a black [GlowFilter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/filters/GlowFilter.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [GlowFilter](http://help.adobe.com/en%5FUS/AS3LCR/Flash%5F10.0/flash/filters/GlowFilter.html) for this

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a glow filter

new GlowFilter(color, alpha, blurX, blurY, strength, quality, inner, knockout);

[Glow Filter Class Reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/filters/GlowFilter.html)

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen here,
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/filters/DropShadowFilter.html#DropShadowFilter%28%29

You should change the first argument,

```
import flash.filters.DropShadowFilter;

var dropShadow:DropShadowFilter = new DropShadowFilter(0., 45, 0x333333, 20, 10, 10, 1, 2, false, false, false); 
container_mc.filters = new Array(dropShadow);
```

or you could change the distance later,

```
dropShadow.distance = 0.;
```

Also, did you realize that the last 3 arguments you used are the defaults, so you could cut that part out to shorten your code,

```
import flash.filters.DropShadowFilter;

var dropShadow:DropShadowFilter = new DropShadowFilter(0., 45, 0x333333, 20, 10, 10, 1, 2); 
container_mc.filters = new Array(dropShadow);
```

Good luck with flash/as3!